# Enable reset button after the form is filled in

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms

I have the following html code:

```
 <form class="form" method="post">
      <h2 id="formheadline" class="options-headline">Change password</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">
          Current password
        </label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" id="old" required = "required" class="form-input"
               placeholder="Current Password"/>
        <span id="old-password-error" class="error-text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">
          New Password
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="new" placeholder="New Password" required = "required"
               class="form-input" minlength="8" maxlength="12" 
               pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">
         New password
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="repeat" placeholder="New password"
               required = "required" class="form-input" minlength="8" maxlength="12"
               pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}"/>
        <span id="new-password-error" class="error-text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row form-row-center">
        <button  type = "reset" id="save-changes-button" class="button button-submit">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I need to make the button disabled until all fields are not empty. 
I tried solving it with the following lines in a `form.js` file:

```
$(function(){
    $('#save-changes-button').button("disabled");
    $("input").on('change keyup',isFormValid);
});

function isFormValid(){
    var formIsValid = isOldPasswordValid()&&isConferemedPasswordValid&&isNewPasswordValid;
    $("buttom[type='reset']").prop("disabled", !formIsValid);
}
function isOldPasswordValid(){
    var oldPasswordInput = $("#old").val();
    if (oldPasswordInput.length == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function isNewPasswordValid(){
    var newPasswordInput = $("#new").val();
    if (newPasswordInput.length == 0){
        return false;
    }
    if (newPasswordInput.length<4){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function isConferemedPasswordValid(){
    var conferemedPasswordInput = $("#repeat").val();
    var newPasswordInput = $("#new").val();
    if (confermedPasswordInput != newPasswordInput){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I'm seeing no reaction when I run it. The button still stays enabled.
I am also not sure if I am connecting the 2 files correctly, is it enough to write `<script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"/>` or is there more to it that I am forgetting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("button[type='reset']").prop("disabled",true);
$("input").on('input',isFormValid);
function isFormValid(){
    var formIsValid = isOldPasswordValid()&&isConferemedPasswordValid()&&isNewPasswordValid();
    $("button[type='reset']").prop("disabled", !formIsValid);
    
}
function isOldPasswordValid(){
    var oldPasswordInput = $("#old").val();
    if (oldPasswordInput.length == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function isNewPasswordValid(){
    var newPasswordInput = $("#new").val();
    if (newPasswordInput.length == 0){
        return false;
    }
    if (newPasswordInput.length<4){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function isConferemedPasswordValid(){
    var conferemedPasswordInput = $("#repeat").val();
    var newPasswordInput = $("#new").val();
    if (conferemedPasswordInput != newPasswordInput){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" method="post">
      <h2 id="formheadline" class="options-headline">Change password</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">
          Current password
        </label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" id="old" required = "required" class="form-input"
               placeholder="Current Password"/>
        <span id="old-password-error" class="error-text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">
          New Password
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="new" placeholder="New Password" required = "required"
               class="form-input" minlength="8" maxlength="12" 
               pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label class="form-label">
         New password
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="repeat" placeholder="New password"
               required = "required" class="form-input" minlength="8" maxlength="12"
               pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}"/>
        <span id="new-password-error" class="error-text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row form-row-center">
        <button  type="reset" id="save-changes-button" class="button button-submit" disabled>
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you query a function at the first line? You can call it directly.

```
$('#save-changes-button').button("disabled");
$("input").on('change keyup',isFormValid);

function isFormValid(){
    var formIsValid = isOldPasswordValid()&&isConferemedPasswordValid&&isNewPasswordValid;
    $("button[type='reset']").prop("disabled", !formIsValid);
}
function isOldPasswordValid(){
    var oldPasswordInput = $("#old").val();
    if (oldPasswordInput.length == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function isNewPasswordValid(){
    var newPasswordInput = $("#new").val();
    if (newPasswordInput.length == 0){
        return false;
    }
    if (newPasswordInput.length<4){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function isConferemedPasswordValid(){
    var conferemedPasswordInput = $("#repeat").val();
    var newPasswordInput = $("#new").val();
    if (confermedPasswordInput != newPasswordInput){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about changing the function that you are using with something more generic like this (add an id to the form so we can use here)

```
<form class="form" method="post" id="change-password">

function isFormValid(){
    var formInvalid = false
    $('#change-password input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
       formInvalid = true
       return false;
    }
    $("button[type='reset']").prop("disabled", formInvalid);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that this was just vanilla javascript, you need jquery for this solution.